# How to generate a Random number for a calculated field in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, random, calculated-field

Is there a way to generate a random number for a calculated field, in a SharePoint list ?

Comment: I am interested to know what you're planning to use this for, care to elaborate?

Comment: My client wanted some kind of protocol, with a random number, for a customers attendance scheduling list. But he already realized the it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a way to do this within the SharePoint UI.

I would create a SharePoint event for the field that would programatically assign the random number whenever the event is fired (i.e. list item updated, list item created, etc...)